# split String[] with seperators and convert it to 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays

There is is a problem in my `c#` code.

I have a string array with 23 values in each line, seperated by a semicolon.
I want to split each value and parse it into an 2D [double] Array that should look like:

[(number of lines),22].

The string array looks like:

> [0]
>   0,00;111,00;0,00;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,10;-0,10;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
>
> [1]
>   0,00;120,00;0,00;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,10;-0,10;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00

The double array should look like:

> [0,0] 0,00
>
> [0,1] 111,00
>
> [0,2] 0,00
>
> [0,3] -1,00

and so on.

Do you have any ideas?

This is my current Code, that does not work.

```
double[,] values = new double[z, 22];
char[] seperator = { ';' };

int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++) {
        values[i, j] = Data[x].Split(seperator);
        x++;                                                
    }
}
```

Comment: We have plenty of ideas. Like, "use a `for` loop". Or, "use String.Split( ';' )".  But we are not a code writing service.  So, start coding it, and come back here if it does not work.

Comment: It seems safe to assume that the `,` character is your decimal separator?

Answer (score 1):

**How you could achieve this:**

I use decimal here if you use double it will get the result `0` from a string like `0,00`. So you can use double but if it can it will shorten it. Whit decimal a string like `0,00` will be 0.00

```
        string[] arr = new string[] { "0,00;111,00;0,00;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,10;-0,10;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00" , "0,00;120,00;0,00;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,10;-0,10;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00" };
        // array conaining decimals
        decimal[,] numbers = new decimal[2,23];

        // loop thrue strings in arr
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            // split that string by ';'
            string[] numberStrings = arr[i].Split(';');
            // loop thrue the result of the splitted strings
            for (int j = 0; j < numberStrings.Length; j++)
            {
                // parse that number from splitted string to decimal an put it on his place in the 2d array
                numbers[i, j] = decimal.Parse(numberStrings[j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your Help! I'm new in programming, so I don't know how to deal with the multi array list. could I convert it into a double [,] array after the loop you wrote me?

Comment: Yes you can you can use `decimal[][] finalArray = multiArray.ToArray();`  You covert the list of decimal arrays to decimal 2d array.

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot! I tried your code, but it didn't work fine for me. Is there a solution, if I just want to get an double [,] array as result and not a decimal [][].

Comment: I've changed my question hopefully this will for fill your needs. Notice that I use decimal instead of double. If you still want to use double just change all the decimal to double instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this code.

```
        String a1 = "0,00;111,00;0,00;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,10;-0,10;-1,00;-1,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00";


        // new array split string by ';'
        String[] arr1 = a1.Split(';');

        int count = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n-----------\nType 1 (only 1 array) \n-----------\n\n\n");

        while ( count <= arr1.Length -1){
            Console.WriteLine(arr1[count].ToString());
            count++;
        }


        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n-----------\nType 2 (multidimensional array) \n-----------\n\n\n");

        // new array split string by ';' and ','
        String[] arr2 = a1.Split(';');
        string[,] arrFinal = new string[23,2];


        // re-start counter
        count = 0;

        while (count <= arr2.Length - 1)
        {
            arrFinal[count, 0] = arr2[count].ToString().Split(',')[0];
            arrFinal[count, 1] = arr2[count].ToString().Split(',')[1];

            Console.WriteLine(arr2[count].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("item ({0},{1}) = {2} | item ({3},{4}) = {5} ", count, "0", arrFinal[count, 0], count, "1", arrFinal[count, 1], arrFinal[count, 1] );
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: It might be useful to provide some context or explanation as to why this solves the problem.

Comment: i get the string lines from a .txt file wherefrom I seperate the values line by line. Afterwards I want to compare several values. Therefore I need the values in an array, so that i can access them quick.